# How to find if dataTable contains column which name starts with abc

Tags: c#, regex, datatable, dataset

In my program I have a dataTable and I´d like to know if is there a column which name starts with abc.
For example I have a DataTable and its name is `abcdef`. I like to find this column using something like this:

```
DataTable.Columns.Constains(ColumnName.StartWith(abc))
```

Because I know only part of the column name, I cannot use a Contains method.
Is there any simple way how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 var datatable = new DataTable();
 var abccolumns = datatable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                   .Where(c => c.ColumnName.StartsWith("abc"));
```